# ASP.NET deployment code?

Tags: asp.net

I have a question regarding uploading an asp.net website to a real web sever. What type of files will be uploaded is it ASP.NET files or is it assemblies?

To be more clear if someone got an access to my ftp and downloaded all the files will he be able to edit those files?

Comment: Any file that has been downloaded from a public source can also be edited.  What are you really asking?

Comment: asp.net sites can be deployed precompiled or not; if precompiled, it's just assemblies, otherwise it's source and dlls

Comment: You need to provide more information on the type of ASP.NET site: WebForms or MVC, if the former, website or web application, precompiled or not.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, an ASP.NET website published on a third-party server (host) is (pre)compiled in a non-updatable way to avoid code modification.

**About source code access**

First point, **precompilation** as Steven said. Depending on your project type, if you don't [precompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb398860%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the source code (`*.cs` in C# or `*.vb` in VB.NET) will be in the deployment package and present in your web site root. By default, it cannot be downloaded via the webserver because of the file extensions but these files are accessible on the file system.

*Note that if you precompile in an updatable mode, the content of your `.aspx`, `.ascx` and `.master` will be readable. Check the link above.*

Second point, **reverse-engineering** : even if you compile and make the effort to put the maximum of your code logic in your compiled code -ie. assemblies-, the source code is fully readable in your assemblies through ['spy' tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector). Furthermore, these assemblies can be **decompiled** -and the source code is back-.

Finally, if you want to prevent source code theft, you have to **obfuscate** your code (assemblies). The role of obfuscation is to make the code unreadable by scattering the sources (classes and methods) and renaming the variables. The code in your final assemblies will be incomprehensible for a human.
It can be somehow decompiled but your code logic will be more difficult to analyze. There is a bunch of [obfuscation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation). I like [Eazfuscator .NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) (last free version is 3.3).

Take a look : [7 Ways to Protect your .NET Code from Reverse-Engineering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169498/7-Ways-to-Protect-your-NET-Code-from-Reverse-Engin)